Inconsistent JSON using Springboot
I'm currently learning Angular using Springboot as back-end. I have an issue with my JSON rendering of one specific entities.
The JSONPath to acess some data is changing from a id to another leading me not to be able to have a consistent way to display data in my Angular front side.
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "name"
)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Game implements SluggerInterface,
        NomenclatureInterface {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    @JsonView(JsonViews.GamePublicView.class)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @JsonView(JsonViews.GameMinimalView.class)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    @JsonView(JsonViews.GamePublicView.class)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "release_date", nullable = false)
    @PastOrPresent
    @JsonView(JsonViews.GamePublicView.class)
    private LocalDate releaseDate;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @JsonView(JsonViews.GamePublicView.class)
    private String image;

    @Column
    @JsonView(JsonViews.GamePublicView.class)
    private String backgroundImage;

    @Column
    @JsonView(JsonViews.GamePublicView.class)
    private String trailer;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonView(JsonViews.GamePublicView.class)
    private Genre genre;

    @JsonView(JsonViews.GamePrivateView.class)
    private String slug;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "publisher_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonView(JsonViews.GamePublicView.class)
    private Publisher publisher;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "business_model_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonView(JsonViews.GamePublicView.class)
    @JsonBackReference
    private BusinessModel businessModel;



    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "game_platform",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "game_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "platform_id")
    )
    @JsonView(JsonViews.GamePublicView.class)
    private List<Platform> platforms = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "classification_id")
    @JsonView(JsonViews.GamePublicView.class)
    private Classification classification;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "game")
    @JsonView(JsonViews.GamePlusReview.class)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public String getField() {
        return name;
    }
    public void addPlatform(Platform platform) {
        if (!platforms.contains(platform)) {
            platforms.add(platform);
        }
    }
}

@Service
@Transactional
@AllArgsConstructor
public class GameServiceImpl implements DAOEntityInterface<Game>, DAOSearchInterface<Game> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GameServiceImpl.class); //Upgrade log event display

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private GameRepository gameRepository;

    //Method to get all
    @Override
    public List<Game> findAll() { return gameRepository.findAllWithDetails(); }


    //Method to get all sorted in case we add many more
    @Override
    public List<Game> findAllSorted() { return gameRepository.findAllByOrderByNameAsc();}

    @Override
    public List<Game> search(String query) {
        return gameRepository.findByGameContainingIgnoreCase(query);
    }

    //Method to find by Id
    public Game findById(Long id) {
        return gameRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
    }

    //Method to find by Slug
    public Game findBySlug(String slug) {
        return gameRepository.findBySlug(slug)
                .orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
    }

    public List<Game> findTop4ByOrderByCountReview() {
        return gameRepository.findTop4ByOrderByCountReview();
    }

    public List<Game> findAllByFieldAndDirection(String field, String direction) {
        Sort sort = Sort.by(Sort.Direction.fromString(direction), field);
        return gameRepository.findAll(sort);
    }

    ///Method to add record in Database
    public Game persist(GameDTO gameDTO, Long id) {
        Game game;
        if (id != null) {
            //Attempt to find a specific game by ID
            game = gameRepository.findById(id)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundCapEntException("Game", "id", id.toString(), "No game found with ID: " + id));
            logger.info("Updating existing game with ID: {}", id);

            game.setName(gameDTO.getName());
            game.setDescription(gameDTO.getDescription());
            game.setReleaseDate(gameDTO.getReleaseDate());
            game.setImage(gameDTO.getImage());
            game.setBackgroundImage(gameDTO.getBackgroundImage());
            game.setTrailer(gameDTO.getTrailer());
            game.setGenre(gameDTO.getGenre());
            game.setPublisher(gameDTO.getPublisher());
            game.setBusinessModel(gameDTO.getBusinessModel());
            game.setPlatforms(gameDTO.getPlatforms());
            game.setClassification(gameDTO.getClassification());
        } else {
            // If no ID is provided, create a new game
            game = new Game();
            game.setName(gameDTO.getName());
            game.setName(gameDTO.getName());
            game.setDescription(gameDTO.getDescription());
            game.setReleaseDate(gameDTO.getReleaseDate());
            game.setImage(gameDTO.getImage());
            game.setBackgroundImage(gameDTO.getBackgroundImage());
            game.setTrailer(gameDTO.getTrailer());
            game.setGenre(gameDTO.getGenre());
            game.setPublisher(gameDTO.getPublisher());
            game.setBusinessModel(gameDTO.getBusinessModel());
            game.setPlatforms(gameDTO.getPlatforms());
            game.setClassification(gameDTO.getClassification());
            logger.info("Creating new game");
        }
        // Save the updated game or the new game
        return gameRepository.saveAndFlush(game);
    }

    //Methode to delete a record
    public void delete(Long id) {
        gameRepository.deleteById(id);
        logger.info("Deleted game with ID: {}", id);
    }

    public List<Game> findAllGamesWithDetails() {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Game> query = cb.createQuery(Game.class);
        Root<Game> game = query.from(Game.class);
        game.fetch("publisher", JoinType.LEFT); // Assure-toi que ces entités sont correctement jointes
        game.fetch("genre", JoinType.LEFT);
        game.fetch("platforms", JoinType.LEFT);
        game.fetch("classification", JoinType.LEFT);
        query.select(game).distinct(true);

        return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    }
}

@Repository
public interface GameRepository extends EntityNomenclatureRepository<Game>, JpaRepository<Game, Long> {

    List<Game> findAllByOrderByNameAsc();

    List<Game> findAllByOrderByNameDesc();

    @Query("SELECT g FROM Game g WHERE LOWER(g.name) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :name, '%'))")
    List<Game> findByGameContainingIgnoreCase(String name);

    @Query("select g from Game g join Review r on g.id = r.game.id group by g.id order by count(r.game.id) desc limit 4")
    List<Game> findTop4ByOrderByCountReview();

    Optional<Game> findBySlug(String slug);

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"publisher", "platforms", "classification", "genre"})
    @Query("SELECT g FROM Game g LEFT JOIN FETCH g.publisher LEFT JOIN FETCH g.genre  LEFT JOIN FETCH g.platforms  LEFT JOIN FETCH g.classification")
    List<Game> findAllWithDetails();
}


@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/game")
public class GameController {

    @Autowired
    private GameServiceImpl gameService;

    @GetMapping
    @JsonView(JsonViews.GamePrivateView.class)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Game>>findAllGamesWithDetails(){
    List<Game> games= gameService.findAllGamesWithDetails();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(games);
    }

// Use in Angular nav search bar
    @GetMapping("/search")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Game>> searchGames(@RequestParam String query) {
        List<Game> games = gameService.search(query);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(games);
    }


    @GetMapping(path = "/sorted")
    @JsonView(JsonViews.GamePrivateView.class)
    public List<Game> getAllByFieldAndDirection(
            @RequestParam String field,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "asc") String direction) {
        return gameService.findAllByFieldAndDirection(field, direction);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/asc")
    @JsonView(JsonViews.GamePrivateView.class)
    List<Game> getAllGameSortedAsc() {
        return gameService.findAllSorted();
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/{id}")
    @JsonView(JsonViews.GamePrivateView.class)
    public Game getGameById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return gameService.findById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/create")
    @JsonView(JsonViews.GamePublicView.class)
    public Game persist(@Validated @RequestBody GameDTO gameDTO) {
        return gameService.persist(gameDTO, null);
    }

    @PutMapping(path = "/edit/{id}")
    @JsonView(JsonViews.GamePrivateView.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Game> updateGame(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody GameDTO gameDTO) {
        Game gameUpdated = gameService.persist(gameDTO, id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(gameUpdated, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(path = "/delete/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        gameService.delete(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
}

Find here the json response
As you can see I followed a few tracks. I first thought the issue came from my front side then realized in my swagger that the json did ot have a consistent structure. I assumed I had an issue with the fetch method, so I specified the Fetch.Eager.
I worked around my JPQL method couldn't find the any resolving.
 @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"publisher", "platforms", "classification", "genre"})
    @Query("SELECT g FROM Game g LEFT JOIN FETCH g.publisher LEFT JOIN FETCH g.genre  LEFT JOIN FETCH g.platforms  LEFT JOIN FETCH g.classification")
    

Any other idea could help at this point, thank you for taking the time to read.
I can provide the other entity if needed in your hunting.

For the moment I found a front solution to handle inconsistent data structures.
Create and use a pipe in Angular to implement reusable logic for transforming data before display.
